# Calling a function in pyrogram from another Python file

Tags: python, function, telegram-bot, pyrogram

In Pyrogram package, how can I call a function from another Python script?

For example, suppose that the Pyrogram function takes two arguments `chat_id` and `text` as input and then send `text` to given `chat_id`.

We know that `app.send_message(chat_id = given_chat_id,text = given_text)` method is send `given_text` to `given_chat_id`,

Suppose there are two files named `run.py` and `tel.py` in the same folder.

File `run.py` should contain this script:

```
from tel import my_func
my_func(given_chat_id, given_text)
```

and `tel.py` should look like this code:

```
from pyrogram import Client
app = Client("my_account")
async def my_func(chat_id, text):
    print("Hello world!")
    await app.send_message(chat_id, text)
app.run()
```

We know it doesn't work. when I run `run.py` file Even the phrase `Hello world!` is not printed.

I don't know how to call it.

Comment: I changed the name of the function to `my_func`. I even added something to print, but that line is not executed.

Comment: I just trying to call `tel.my_func`. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**You should Use decorator before your function**

```
from pyrogram import Client

app = Client("my_account")


@app.on_message()
def log(client, message):
    print(message)
app.run()
```